# Inform resharper that an out variable will only be null if the function returns false;

Tags: c#, null, resharper, contracts

I have the following function that follows the TryGet pattern with an out param that if null will return false, if it is not null it will return true

```
public bool TryGetFileFormat(string extension, [CanBeNull] out IFileFormat fileFormatter)
{
    fileFormatter = Plugins?.FirstOrDefault(plugin => plugin?.FileExtension != null && plugin.FileExtension.Equals(extension));
    return (fileFormatter != null);
}
```

I then call the function with the following code:

```
IFileFormat fileFormatPlugin;
if (_pluginLoader.TryGetFileFormat(extension, out fileFormatPlugin))
{
    fileFormatPlugin.DoStuff();
```

Resharper then warns me that fileFormatPlugin could be null. How can I tell resharper that it will only be null if the function returns false?

Edit I suspect I can handle this with ContractAnnotation somehow, but unsure the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following contract annotation causes resharper to only warn about null reference if you use the value when the function has returned false

```
[ContractAnnotation("fileFormatter : null => false")]
public bool TryGetFileFormat(string extension, [CanBeNull]out IFileFormat fileFormatter){
    fileFormatter = Plugins?.FirstOrDefault(plugin => plugin?.FileExtension != null && plugin.FileExtension.Equals(extension));
    return (fileFormatter != null);
}
```